# Vue JS 2 - Vuetify and Vulidate on openning modal

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuelidate

so there is my problem.

I simply put a form in a dialog, when I open it for the first time it's all good, vuelidate works, errors if my fields are empty works too. I complete the form send it, it close the modal.

But then, when I open it to complete it again,errors are display for no reason :
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2I6m.png)

```
<v-select
 v-model="selectedDoctor"
 :items="doctors"
 item-text="username"
 item-value="id"
 :label="$t('components.homeCardTeleconsultation.doctor')"
 :error-messages="
 fieldErrors($v.selectedDoctor, $t('components.homeCardTeleconsultation.doctor'))"
 return-object
 />

  addTeleconsultant () {
    this.$v.$touch()
    if (this.$v.$invalid || this.isSaving) {
    } else {
    const query = {
      xxxxx
    }

    this.$repositories.teleconsultations.create(query).then((reponse) => {
      this.teleconsults = reponse.data
    })
    this.close()
  }
```

It seems like vuelidate check if my fields are required when I open the modal but never the first time. I really don't understand what's going on so if someone have a solution or something...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just one line `this.$v.$reset()`